# Determine which JS file/line is modifying an element on my page

Tags: javascript, dom, stack-trace, onload-event

I need to determine which JS file/line is modifying an element on my page. I'm trying to find a needle in a haystack here.  For example, I'm digging through 35 .js files to find out which file is responsible for a change to some text on a webpage. It seems like too much work for such a simple task.

It could be changing it in many many different ways using jQuery, or just javascript.  Method is unknown.  But it happens on page load.

Is it possible to see this information in Chrome (Developer Tools)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Google Chrome:

1. Right-click on the element you want to detect changes to.
2. In the Elements pane of the Developer Tools that shows up, right click on the element again (in this case a `<label>` element.
3. Choose `Break on…` ▶ `Attributes Modifications` (or `Subtree Modifications`)
4. Reload. Voila! You are stopped at the JavaScript code making the modification.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this actually does work.  YES, this is soooo cool!

Comment: Helped me as well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I hope following link would help you

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-mutation-events

It basically tells you how to track down events that mutated given dom element

Comment: Wow, this is great... hmmm, just hope it works on page load.  Kinda hard to get it when the page loads, cause it happens so fast.

Comment: @SolomonClosson I think you can simply add the break point and refresh the page? or am I missing something?